# echo image in database using path folder,

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
       //connect to mysql and select database
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('4dberlin') or die("Can not select database");


 //fetch data from MySQL
 $result = mysql_query("select * from photos ");

 //iterate over each row and do what you want.
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
      $location = $row['image'];

    echo "<img src='" . $row['image'] . "' height='130' width='220'> ";
 }

     ?>
```

the path of my images in localhost/admin/uploads . i dont know why not displaying my images.

Comment: `$row['image']` contain file name or full path?

Comment: sidenote: It would be best if you were to save the full path with the image name, rather than just the image name. You're restricted to using only 1 path, should you want to show different images from other folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question it seems that `$row['image']` contain name of image.

So your code should look like

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
      $location = $row['image'];

    echo "<img src='http://localhost/admin/uploads/" . $row['image'] . "' height='130' width='220'> ";
 }
```

where `http://localhost/admin/uploads/` is the path where your image store.

Comment: yes that is the path of my images restore, and i want only to display the image in my index, but i dont know why not displaying

Comment: Thank you! it display already! after 8min i will check your answer

Comment: use `fire bug` to check the path of your image

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
   //connect to mysql and select database


mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());


mysql_select_db('4dberlin') or die("Can not select database");

//fetch data from MySQL


$result = mysql_query("select * from photos ");



//iterate over each row and do what you want.


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $location = $row['image'];

echo "<img src='admin/uploads/" . $row['image'] . "' height='130' width='220'> ";
 }

 ?>
```